# EnumDropDownListFor extending an existing database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, enums

My application is MVC 5.2, using EF 6.1 Database First. Never used Enum before, I am trying to store a key value from dropdownlist in the following:

```
      public partial class Sleep {
      public Nullable<int> SleepId {get;set;}
       }
```

To take advantage of the new @HTML.EnumDropDownListFor, I added the following partial class

```
  public enum SleepValues : int
            {
            Good = 1,
            Bad = 2,
            NotWell = 3
            }
```

and changed the original class to

```
public Nullable<SleepValues > SleepId {get;set;}
```

I get the following error:

```
The entity type Sleep is not part of the model for the current context.
```

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Do you have Sleep table in your db?

Comment: Yes.  It has Id, SleepId, and theDay.

Comment: Did you add the entity to your context such as context.Add(entity)? What is the EntityState of your object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I was able to reproduce this issue.I think you need to explicitly change the type of your Property  SleepId  to enum in your model i.e. edmx file.
you can try following steps and see if that resolves your problem:

- First remove the existing SleepValues enumeration
- Go to edmx file and right click on SleepId property.
- Click on 'Convert to Enum' option
- Now define your enumeration through "Add Enum Type" dialog box that comes up.

Refer below link for details.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj248772.aspx